# Changing UIViews height goes to the bottom but should go up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to do a bar-graph animation. Where the bars go up when the view loads. Here is what I do.

```
CGRect bar1Frame = self.rootView6.bar1.frame;

    bar1Frame.size.height = 181;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

    self.rootView6.bar1.frame = bar1Frame;


    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

The problem is that the bars height goes to the bottom of the view instead of going to the top.

Anyone can help me?

[image]

Comment: You need to update the `y` position too to make it upwards. example `bar1Frame.origin.y = bar1Frame.origin.y - 181;`

Comment: `bar1Frame.size.height = -181;` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the y origin of the `bar1Frame` as well with

`bar1Frame.origin.y = bar1Frame.origin.y - 181;`

```
bar1Frame.size.height = 181;
```

and apply the animations as you did. Doing so will show your bar above the horizontal line of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the y-position of the UIView.
Eg: if you need to change height to 100 then

```
bar1Frame.origin.y = bar1Frame.origin.y-100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect bar1Frame = self.rootView6.bar1.frame;
bar1Frame.size.height = 181;
bar1.Frame.origin.y -= bar1Frame.size.height;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
self.rootView6.bar1.frame = bar1Frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```